# How to center my photo when the width of my viewport is less than 1235px?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I'm creating my website and making it mobile-friendly with @media tags on CSS. I have an image of the empire state building that aligns to the right instead of center whenever the viewport is less than 1235px. I was wondering what the root of this problem is? I tried using a @media tag to center the image with "text-align: center;" but no luck.

[It currently looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCUtf.png)

The target image that I want to center is called "NYC_icon"

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="section1">

     <div id="NYC_icon">
         <img src="C:\Users\LYind\OneDrive\Documents\Full-Stack Developer 2020 Course\Personal Website HTML\Images\home2.png"
             alt="NYC">
     </div>

     <div id="Mini_Bio">
         <h1>
             Linda Ye
         </h1>
         <h2>
             <i>NYC
             </i>
         </h2>
         <p>
             Aspiring <strong> coder</strong>, business
             <strong> woman</strong>, avid
             <strong> runner</strong>, and weekend
             <strong> chef</strong>.
         </p>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.section1 {
margin: 80px;
padding: 30px 20px;}

#NYC_icon {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 200px;
vertical-align: top;}

@media (max-width:1278px) {
#NYC_icon img{
    text-align: center;}}
```

Comment: Try setting the margin-left to 0px in your media query for your #NYC_icon.

Comment: To center your image inside to #NYC_icon, you could apply the following CSS to #NYC_icon:
display: flex; justify-content: center;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try applying the `text-align: center` to the div that contains the image. And also specify `margrin: 0` when width of the screen is less than 1235px. so it allows that the image can be horizontally centered.

```
@media (max-width:1235px) {
  #NYC_icon {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would recommend that you head over to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout) and review the basics of layout. I do not understand what your are trying to do with the div which contains the image.
With regards to this particular case, experiment with the following changes:

1. Open the browser developer tools and inspect the element in questions. See what styles are applied.
2. I would recommend that if you are a beginner, set a 1px solid black border on all elements to visually see if what you are trying to do is working as you expect.
3. Finally, with regards to this particular problem, you can try many different things. I think that if you change the style of the img to {display:block; margin: 0px auto} it will be centered. Just drop the containing div altogether.
   Also have a look at this [resource.](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html#block)

Answer (score 0):

The `<img>` is not centered at all, Not at more nor less than 1235px viewport.

[image]

I made the relevant changes to the code to make the images centered at all times, The code is heavily commented, If you have any questions please do ask.

```css
/*  To illustrate Not needed */

body * {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
}


/* To illustrate Not needed */

.section1 {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 30px 20px;
}

#NYC_icon {
  /*  To let the element fill the space so we can center the img inside */
  display: block;
  
  
  /* text-align on the parent of the element we want to align */
  /* text-align proerty only aligns inline level elements */
  /* inline level elements are elements with display value
   * set to inline or inline-[something]
   */
  text-align: center;
  
  
  /*     margin-left: 200px; removed not needed*/
  /*     vertical-align: top;  removed not needed*/
}
```

```html
<div class="section1">

  <div id="NYC_icon">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300" alt="NYC">
  </div>

  <div id="Mini_Bio">
    <h1>
      Linda Ye
    </h1>
    <h2>
      <i>NYC
             </i>
    </h2>
    <p>
      Aspiring <strong> coder</strong>, business
      <strong> woman</strong>, avid
      <strong> runner</strong>, and weekend
      <strong> chef</strong>.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```